# ClassCastException when setting default values for support library preference

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences

I have a custom preference, which extends from `android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference`. Everything works fine, except when I call

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

which causes the app to crash with `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.my.project.EditTextPreferenceWithSummary cannot be cast to android.preference.Preference` on the above line.

My custom class is a simple extension of `android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference`:

```
public class EditTextPreferenceWithSummary extends EditTextPreference
```

So how can I call `setDefaultValues()` and avoid the `ClassCastException`?

Comment: wrong import. you need PreferenceManager from the support library

Comment: Good catch! I just realized it too...

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that the wrong version of PerformanceManager was imported into my classes.  The import must be updated to reference the v7.performance.PerformanceManager.